# Does a list of all perakim in shas with summary of each perek exist?

Tags: talmud-gemara, shas

Is there an existing list of all chapters in shas and include a brief summary of each perek?

Comment: [Here's a list](https://wiki.jewishbooks.org.il/mediawiki/wiki/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8:%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%A1), but no summaries.

Comment: Mishnah or Gemarah?

Comment: Someone could piece one together using Meiri, Kehati, or Artscroll.

Answer (score 5):

(work in progress — community wiki for others to add to this)

### Seder Zeraim:

See Wikipedia for:
[**Brachot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berakhot_(tractate)#Structure_and_content)
[**Demai**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demai_(tractate)#Structure)
[**Kilayim**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kil%27ayim_(tractate)#Structure)
[**Shevi'it**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shevi%27it_(tractate)#Structure_and_content)
[**Terumot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terumot#Structure_and_content)
[**Challah**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challah_(tractate)#Contents)
[**Bikkurim**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bikkurim_(tractate)#Contents)

**Peah** (excerpted from [1])

- Chapter 1 — basic definition: amount, location, types of produce subject
- Chapter 2 — definition of the area of land defined as a field from which a single portion of peah must be designated: grain fields; orchards; ambiguous cases
- Chapter 3 — ambiguous cases (cont.); minimum size of a field
- Chapter 4 — distributing peah to the poor; a general discussion of when produce becomes subject to the laws of gleanings, forgotten sheaves, and peah; leket: definition, ambiguous cases
- Chapter 5 — leket: ambiguous cases (cont.); distribution; collection of poor-offerings in general; shichecha: definition
- Chapter 6 — shichecha: ambiguous cases; scriptural basis; types of produce
- Chapter 7 — shichecha of olive trees; grapes: peret
- Chapter 8 — ma'aser ani; definitions of poor person

**Ma'aserot** (excerpted from [1])

- Chapter 1 — conditions under which produce becomes subject to the law; procedure by which harvested produce is rendered liable to the removal of tithes
- Chapter 2 — acquisition of another's untithed produce in four modes; purchases; barter
- Chapter 3 — barter; lost produce found by another; bringing produce from the field into the courtyard or home
- Chapter 4 — preparation of untithed produce for use in a meal; produce which is edible but is normally not deemed food
- Chapter 5 — produce taken from the field prior to the harvest of the crop; produce which is sold or purchased while inedible; produce which is insufficiently processed, or produce the processing of which is in doubt; produce which is not grown in the Land of Israel, or which is not food

**Ma'aser Sheni** (excerpted from [1])

- Chapter 1 — improper use of consecrated food/coins
- Chapter 2 — proper use of consecrated food; proper transference of the status of second tithe to and from coins: from coins to coins
- Chapter 3 — from coins to produce and back
- Chapter 4 — before the produce has been in Jerusalem; produce and coins the status of which is in doubt
- Chapter 5 — produce of a planting's fourth year; law of removal

**Orlah** (excerpted from [1])

- Chapter 1 — definition of terms: fruit tree, planting, fruit
- Chapter 2 — mixtures of forbidden and permitted produce
- Chapter 3 — prohibition against the use of orlah; resolution of doubts

### Seder Moed

See Wikipedia for:
[**Shabbat**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat_(Talmud)#Structure_and_content)
[**Pesachim**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesachim#Structure_and_content)
[**Rosh Hashanah**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Hashanah_(tractate)#Mishna)
[**Ta'anit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%27anit_(Talmud)#Summary_of_the_Mishnah_and_Babylonian_Talmud)

**Eruvin** (excerpted from [4])

- Chapter 1 — forming an alley-way into a single domain; areas occupied by caravans
- Chapter 2 — well in a public domain; large fields
- Chapter 3 — the eruv, a symbolic meal for establishing joint ownership of a courtyard or for establishing symbolic residence for purposes of travel on Shabbat
- Chapter 4 — the eruv and violating the Shabbat limit
- Chapter 5 — defining the Shabbat limit of a town
- Chapter 6 — the eruv and the courtyard
- Chapter 7 — areas which may be deemed either distinct from one another or as a commingled domain, so that the residents have the choice of preparing a joint eruv or two separate ones; shittuf and alleyway
- Chapter 8 — more on shittuf and alleyway; neglecting the eruv for a courtyard; eruv for more than one courtyard
- Chapter 9 — more on eruv for more than one courtyard; the eruv and the area of roofs
- Chapter 10 — the public domain in general

**Shekalim** (excerpted from [4])

- Chapter 1 — the imposition of the obligation to pay
- Chapter 2 — transporting the shekel; me'ila
- Chapter 3 — taking up shekalim for the public offerings
- Chapter 4 — disposition of the shekalim for various offerings
- Chapter 5 — temple administration; selling offerings; collecting other funds in the temple
- Chapter 6 — more on collecting other funds in the temple
- Chapter 7 — disposing of coins and objects found in and near the temple
- Chapter 8 — disposing of coins and objects found in Jerusalem; tum'ah and the parochet

**Yoma** (excerpted from [4])

- Chapter 1 — preparing the kohen gadol for yom kippur; clearing ashes off the altar
- Chapter 2 — more clearing ashes; casting lots; who offers the tamid
- Chapter 3 — more on tamid; morning ketoret; kohen gadol's bull; materials of items in the temple
- Chapter 4 — taking lots for the goats; crimson thread; sin offering for the kohanim; comparison of the ketoret on normal days vs yom kippur
- Chapter 5 — inside ketoret rite; sin offering for the people; purification of golden altar; rules regarding the order of the service
- Chapter 6 — scapegoat and its rules
- Chapter 7 — yom kippur rite finishes with Torah reading and prayer
- Chapter 8 — forbidden acts on yom kippur; rules for children, pregnant people, sick people; saving lives in cases of doubt; general ideas of atonement

**Sukkah** (excerpted from [4])

- Chapter 1 — the sukkah and its roofing
- Chapter 2 — sukkah and beds or on a wagon or boat; obligation to dwell in the sukkah
- Chapter 3 — details of lulav and etrog
- Chapter 4 — taking the lulav; aravot; Hallel; water libations
- Chapter 5 — playing the flute; simḥat beit hasho'eva; shofar during offerings; sukkot offerings

**Beitzah** (excerpted from [4])

- 1:1–3:1 — the Houses and other authorities
- 3:2–3:8 — designating food before the festival for use on the festival
- 4:1–5:2 — doing actions connected with preparing food on a festival day in a different manner from ordinary days; other restrictions
- 5:3–5:7 — ownership and Shabbat limits

**Megillah** (excerpted from [4])

- Chapter 1 — when to read the megillah; sequence of mishnayot of the form "there is no difference between ... and ... except ..."
- Chapter 2 — who/how/where about reading the megillah
- Chapter 3 — disposition of synagogue property; rules for reading Torah in synagogue worship
- Chapter 4 — the Torah readings; conduct in the synagogue

**Mo'ed Katan** (excerpted from [4])

- Chapter 1 — ḥol hamo'ed in the fields; miscellaneous rulings
- Chapter 2 — cases of emergency and loss; commerce
- Chapter 3 — those who can get a haircut or wash clothes on ḥol hamo'ed; burial of the dead and mourning on ḥol hamo'ed

**Ḥagigah** (excerpted from [4])

- Chapter 1 — the olat re'iya; homiletic material
- Chapter 2 — more homiletic material; offerings and Shabbat; gradations of strictness regarding tum'ah
- Chapter 3 — more on gradations of strictness regarding tum'ah; holy things and the festival

### Seder Nashim

See Wikipedia for:
[**Nedarim**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nedarim_(Talmud)#Contents)
[**Nazir**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazir_(Talmud)#Summary_of_the_Mishnayot)

### Seder Nezikin

See Wikipedia for:
[**Bava Batra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bava_Batra#Mishnah)
[**Sanhedrin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanhedrin_(tractate)#Summary_of_Sanhedrin)
[**Shevuot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shevu%27ot#Mishnah)
[**Eduyot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduyot_(Talmud)#Mishnah)
[**Avodah Zarah**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avodah_Zarah#Mishna)
[**Avot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirkei_Avot#Structure_of_the_work)
[**Horayot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horayot#Mishnah)

### Seder Kodashim

See Wikipedia for:
[**Hullin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hullin#Mishnah)
[**Bechorot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekhorot#Mishna)
[**Temurah**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temurah_(Talmud)#Mishnah)
[**Keritot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keritot#Mishnah)
[**Me'ilah**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me%27ilah#Mishnah)
[**Tamid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamid#Mishnah)
[**Middot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middot_(Talmud)#Structure)
[**Kinnim**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinnim)

### Seder Taharot

See Wikipedia for:
[**Parah**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parah#Contents)
[**Taharot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tohorot_(tractate)#Contents)
[**Zavim**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zavim#Contents)
[**Tevul Yom**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tevul_Yom#Contents)
[**Yadayim**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yadayim#Mishnah)

**Keilim** (by magicker72)

- Chapter 1 — general introduction to seder taharot; levels of uncleanness
- Chapter 2 — earthenware utensils: breakage; *toch*; torches
- Chapter 3 — earthenware utensils: damage that purifies
- Chapter 4 — earthenware utensils: shards; rims
- Chapters 5-7 — earthenware ovens/stoves: when it starts/stops being susceptible
- Chapter 8 — earthenware ovens/stoves: partitions in utensils; *tsamid patil*; imparting impurity to stoves
- Chapter 9 — earthenware ovens/stoves: impure objects found inside; *tsamid patil*
- Chapter 10 — details on *tsamid patil*
- Chapter 11 — metal utensils: flat utensils; named utensils; utensils remade from old metal
- Chapter 12 — metal utensils: susceptible in some contexts but not in others; unfinished utensils
- Chapter 13 — damaged metal utensils; part wood/part metal utensils
- Chapter 14 — damaged metal utensils; repurposed damaged utensils; purifying metal utensils
- Chapter 15 — wood/leather/bone utensils: what's susceptible
- Chapter 16 — wood/leather/bone utensils: becoming (un)susceptible; contextual susceptibility
- Chapter 17 — measurements for purity; measurements in general; utensils made from sea animals or seaweed; receptacles
- Chapter 18 — how to measure capacity; what is attached to a container; beds; tefillin
- Chapter 19 — utensils for sitting/lying: beds; counters/satchels/blankets
- Chapter 20 — utensils for sitting/lying: pillows; mattresses; troughs; sticks; chairs; sheets
- Chapter 21 — attachments of utensils
- Chapter 22 — sitting utensils that have pieces removed
- Chapter 23 — items inside other items; *merkav*/*moshav*; nets
- Chapter 24 — utensils that come in three forms: susceptible to *midras*, susceptible to *tumat met*, insusceptible
- Chapter 25 — *toch* and *achorayim* (inside and outside); secondary attached utensils
- Chapter 26 — leather utensils
- Chapter 27/28 — cloth utensils
- Chapter 29 — secondary parts of items, and sizes for which they are considered attached
- Chapter 30 — glass utensils

**Ahilot/Ohalot** (excerpted from [2])

- Chapter 1 — introductory proems
- Chapter 2 — modes/sources of uncleanness
- Chapter 3 — modes/sources of uncleanness (cont.); openings/sizes of tents
- Chapter 4 — subdivisions of tents
- Chapter 5 — utensil as cover for a tent; utensils joining with walls
- Chapter 6 — walls of a tent and how they're subdivided
- Chapter 7 — walls/openings of tents; sloping sides of tents
- Chapter 8 — utensils cannot be tents; composition of tents
- Chapter 9 — objects that are sometimes utensils, sometimes tents
- Chapter 10 — open areas separate from surrounding covered area; utensils joining with walls
- Chapter 11 — segments/sizes of tents; utensils joining with walls
- Chapter 12 — segments/sizes of tents; utensils joining with walls; beams in a tent
- Chapter 13 — openings of tents; clean substances in tent apertures
- Chapter 14 — sizes of tents
- Chapter 15 — subdivisions of tents; forecourt of a burial area
- Chapter 16 — cleaning out a field in which a corpse is found
- Chapter 17 — grave-areas
- Chapter 18 — grave-areas; land/dwellings of gentiles

**Negaim** (excerpted from [2])

- Chapter 1 — introductory proem
- Chapter 2 — negaim in general
- Chapter 3 — negaim in general (cont.); Lev 13:2, 18-28, 29-37, 40-44, 47-59, Lev 14:33-53
- Chapter 4 — bright spot
- Chapter 5 — doubts in negaim
- Chapter 6 — relationship of quick flesh and spreading; places on the human being that are not susceptible to uncleanness
- Chapter 7 — places not susceptible to uncleanness (cont.); removing symptoms of uncleanness
- Chapter 8 — breaking forth over the entire body
- Chapter 9 — the boil and burning
- Chapter 10 — scalls; baldspot
- Chapter 11 — negaim on garments
- Chapter 12/13 — negaim on houses
- Chapter 14 — process of purification of the leper

**Mikvaot** (excerpted from [3])

- Chapter 1 — different kinds of gatherings of water on the ground, regarding ritual purity
- Chapter 2 — uncertainty in immersion; drawn water; mud mixed with water
- Chapter 3 — water falling into a mikvah; how to fix a mikva that was invalidated by drawn water
- Chapter 4 — drawn water (cont.)
- Chapter 5 — diverted springs and drawn water; seas; waves; dams
- Chapter 6 — intermingling mikvahs
- Chapter 7 — completing a mikvah; things falling into a mikvah
- Chapter 8 — purity of Israel; ba'al keri; immersing person with items
- Chapter 9 — interpositions during immersion
- Chapter 10 — immersing items that contain items/have attachments; where does the mikvah water need to reach; measurements of food/water that render impure; impure items inside body

---

[1] *The Law of Agriculture in the Mishnah and the Tosefta*, ed. Jacob Neusner
[2] *A History of the Mishnaic Law of Purities*, Jacob Neusner
[3] Kehati commentary on mishnah
[4] *A History of the Mishnaic Law of Appointed Times*, Jacob Neusner